# return array based on content count swift

Tags: swift

I am filtering an array based on an id contained. I have four items in an array with different `id` but the same `serviceId` I am filtering a base array while checking if ID matches the one from another array.

```
    let flattenArray = [
       {
          "id":1,
          "name":"abc"
       },
       {
          "id":2,
          "name":"joe"
       },
       {
          "id":3,
          "name":"aby"
       }
    ]

struct MainElement: Codable {
    var id: Int?
    var name: String?

}

typealias Main = [MainElement]
        
        let toFilter = [
       {
          "id":"1a",
          "serviceId":1
       },
       {
          "id":"1b",
          "serviceId":1
       },
       {
          "id":"1c",
          "serviceId":1
       },
       {
          "id":"1d",
          "serviceId":1
       }
    ]

// MARK: - ServiceElement
struct ServiceElement: Codable {
    var id: String?
    var serviceId: Int?
}

typealias Service = [ServiceElement]

        let filteredBill = Array(flattenArray).filter { service in
                        toFilter.contains(where: { $0.serviceId == service.id        })}
```

I want filtered bill to become `[{"id": 1, "name": "abc"}, {"id": 1, "name": "abc"}, {"id": 1, "name": "abc"}, {"id": 1, "name": "abc"}]`  since the serviceId appears 4 times

currently only one is returned

Comment: Could you please post proper swift code, dictionaries are written with [] and not {}. And also explain the connection between flattenArray and toFilter

Comment: @JoakimDanielson that, an array of objects.

Comment: How? I have reformatted the json with https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#

Comment: You have an array of "Service" and an array of "Item", but you want an array of Service in the end, no? Or is that only JSON not parsed?

Comment: If I take you code and paste it into a playground I get compilation errors since it isn't swift, if it is json then post it as such but I don't see the point because the question isn't about json decoding, right?. Please post a reproducible example

Comment: Okay @JoakimDanielson, I would paste the object in swift.

Comment: Check now @JoakimDanielson

Comment: Your sample is badly chosen. I would have  put `{ "id":"1c", "serviceId":2 }`, with its corresponding value, because it might be unclear for the transformation later.

Comment: Yes, @Larme thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your code isn't "valid" as such, we can assume that you have a `Service` and an `Item` struct.

```
struct Service {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}

struct Item {
    let id: String
    let serviceId: Int
}
```

Then we populate:

```
let services = [Service(id: 1, name: "abc"),
                Service(id: 2, name: "joe"),
                Service(id: 3, name: "aby")]
let items = [Item(id: "1a", serviceId: 1),
             Item(id: "1b", serviceId: 1),
             Item(id: "1v", serviceId: 1),
             Item(id: "1d", serviceId: 1)]
```

And to get your result, as I guess you want an array of `Service` from an Array of `Item`.

So you want a transformation, not a filtering. So it's `map()`/`compactMap()`, not `filter()`:

```
let transformed = items.compactMap { anItem in
    return services.first(where: { $0.id == anItem.serviceId })
}
```

Explainations:

For each `Item` in `items`, we check if there is a corresponding `Service` in `services`. If it's in it, we return that `Service` found, else, we return `nil` (and we don't add it to the transformation).

With a more manual for loop:

```
var transformed = [Service]()
for (_, anItem) in items.enumerated() {
    if let serviceFound = services.first(where: { $0.id == anItem.serviceId }) {
        transformed.append(serviceFound)
    }
}
```